# How to Persist State Between Animations in CSS3?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I was hoping css3 animations, especially when I mark it as "forwards" would actually change my element's transforms. But it doesn't.

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/3b3f6oyx/

*---USE CHROME BROWSER---*

HTML:

```
<div style='position:fixed;bottom:10px'>
<button onclick='down()'>Go Down</button>
<button onclick='right()'>Go Right</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animdownkf {
    0% {  }
    100% { transform: translateY(100px); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animrightkf {
    0% {  }
    100% { transform: translateX(100px); }
}

#box {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:black;
}

button {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
.animdown { 
        -webkit-animation:1s animdownkf forwards;
}

.animright { 
        -webkit-animation:1s animrightkf forwards;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function down() {
        $('#box').removeClass('animright');
        $('#box').addClass('animdown');
}

function right() {
        $('#box').removeClass('animdown');
        $('#box').addClass('animright');
}
```

What I'd like it to do is persist state, so if I clicked on "go down" it would go down, and then if I clicked on "go right" it would go right FROM THE LOCATION it is currently at.

But it doesn't seem to do this. I know css3 transitions allows to do this but I specifically want css3 animations because I need to use keyframes. I just want my 100% to change the actual element's style. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What you're looking for actually seems like it might work much better with CSS transitions; it's a similar concept to animations, and should also get the same hardware acceleration, but is better suited to simple animations that bring an object directly from one state to another; they can usually account for variations in properties due to existing animations (ie, un-hovering a node in the middle of its hover animation will not cause it to teleport to its final hover position before moving back)

Answer (score 0):

You need jquery for that...

http://jsfiddle.net/swestphal/9kanuLc5/

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#moveright').click(function() {
    $('#box').animate({
    'marginLeft' : "+=100px" //moves right
    });
});

$('#movedown').click(function() {
    $('#box').animate({
    'marginTop' : "+=100px" //moves down
    });
});


  });
  </script>

  <button id="moveright">Move right</button> <button id="movedown">Move     Down</button><div id="box" style="position:absolute;">x</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but I was specifically looking for transforms/translates not margins. (because I want this hardware accelerated)